# convergence of the integral (with parameter)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Find all values of the parameter $c$ for which the following integral is convergent:

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty}  \frac{dx}{(\ln x)^c(x^2-x)^{2c}}.$$

Please help me solve it or give a hint.

Comment: What is $c$ supposed to represent? I assume it's a constant?

Comment: Yes, c is constant parameter $\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $x=1$, $\ln{x} \sim x-1$ so that the integrand in this neighborhood behaves as

$$\frac{1}{x^{2 c} (x-1)^{3 c}}$$

so for convergence of the integral, $c \lt 1/3$.

As $x \to \infty$, however, the integrand behaves as

$$\frac{1}{(\ln{x})^c x^{4 c}}$$

In this case, we would need $c \gt 1/4$ for convergence of the integral.  (The log piece has no impact on the convergence criteria here.)  Therefore, the range of $c$ for which the integral converges is $1/4 \lt c \lt 1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{y^\alpha}$ converges only for $\alpha<1$, $\int_1^\infty \frac{dy}{y^\alpha}$ converges only for $\alpha>1$,
$$\ln(1+y)\sim y, \quad y \to 0$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^{\beta}}=0, \quad \forall \beta>0.$$

Comment: still dont know what to do. What integral convergence tests to use?

Comment: ok, i know how to use your hint, but now need to show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2-x)^{2c}}$ is converges when $ 1/4<c<1/3$

Comment: For details on how to use these hints see Ron Gordon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the convergence in 1 and in $+ \infty$. i will give you some hints for the letter problem. What you want to use is the ratio test.
First of all revrite the problem in this form: $$ \int_3^ \infty \frac{1}{x^{4c}ln^c(x)(1+o(1))}dx$$ Now if c>1/4 your integral converges by ratio test with 1/x^4c. To know what happens at c=1/4, you just need to solve $$\int_3^\infty \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{ln^{1/4}(x)}dx,$$ (DONOTREAD!!

what about a change of variable?)

P.S.: at 1 try using Taylor on the logarithm!